# Why is oldestEntryTime in table's streaming buffer over 36 hours ago?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to run a `DELETE` statement on that table, it fails because

```
UPDATE or DELETE DML statements are not supported over
table <tableName> with streaming buffer
```

I've read elsewhere on SO that the buffer is flushed at least every ~90 minutes. However, the streaming buffer for this table has been around for > 36 hours.

The response from

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectId>/datasets/<dataset>/tables/<tableName>?fields=streamingBuffer
```

is

```
{
 "streamingBuffer": {
  "estimatedRows": "2",
  "estimatedBytes": "202",
  "oldestEntryTime": "1483503840000" // 2017-01-04T04:24:00.000Z
 }
}
```

Is this normal? If not, how can I force flush the streaming buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was bad caching, perpetrated by the BigQuery API Explorer used in the documentation pages. In particular, I was using the tool on the [Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) reference page to check the response from

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectId>/datasets/<dataset>/tables/<tableName>?fields=streamingBuffer`

Inspecting the Network console in Chrome revealed that Google's API continually responds with `304 Not Modified`, until you open a new browser session, at which point it returns `200` with an accurate response.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browser will cache the the result based on your local configuration. You can try to check the the information with a new browser window or issue a query directly with the BigQuery client libraries mentioned in the BigQuery documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries